# Grant/Revoke permissions on a service executing

Tags: linux, bash, user-permissions

I'm using a service on which I'd like to write a script to be able to grant and revoke group on real time (while it's running).

For now, I execute `usermod -aG group user` on the service before running it. It's working fine, but if I do the same command while it's already started, the user's mod isn't effective until I restart the service.

Is there a way to do it properly ?

Comment: There's no trivial way to do so. Have a look at this [cross site ducplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out) for more details.

Comment: Not even a bashism -- this isn't trivial to do in *any* language. What's your actual goal? There might be a better way to achieve it, f/e, by passing a file descriptor opened by a process with more privileges over a UNIX socket over to the service. Or if your service's nature isn't highly stateful, reworking it to use more transient processes (as via socket activation) could solve your problem by having it start a new session / call / &c. and pick up user configurations thus.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I'm running Sonarqube on a Docker Container with a scaner  that must be able to read project and write documents in it. I want the user of the container to be able to run the container with groups to add to the sonarqube user of the container to define the project's visibility for Sonarqube, it works. However, what does not work is to also add/remove groupes when it's already executing.